# Show/Hide checkboxes based on values in an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

New to Angular and javascript and been wracking my brain for 2 days. I have a table in html where I need to show and hide checkboxes. Each row has 5 checkboxes. What will be visible depends on the FieldName and the index in the FieldName's array. I've commented the code below, and I hope it explains what I've tried.

The angular code on the html page looks like this, with the number ranging from 0 to 4. -- 
ng-show="ShowCheckbox(info.FieldName, 0)"

The javascript looks like --

```
$scope.ShowCheckbox = function (FieldName, index) {       
// FieldName is "MandatedMaterials", "AgencyAgmt", etc.

    var MandatedMaterials = [true, true, false, false, false];
    var AgencyAgmt = [true, true, false, false, false];

    return FieldName[index];  
    // This is what I really really want to work.
    // Only MandatedMaterials[2] and AgencyAgmt[3] return false

    // My experiments to narrow down the problem.
    //if (FieldName == "MandatedMaterials")          
    // works, so FieldName is coming from index.cshtml

    //if (index == 3)
    // works, same thing as above

    //if (MandatedMaterials[0] == true)              
    // works, in that it showed all checkboxes

    //if (AgencyAgmt[0] == true)                     
    // works, same as above

    //if (FieldName[0] == true)                      
    // NOPE -- should show all checkboxes, but instead none

    //if (FieldName[0])                              
    // works, in that it shows all checkboxes

// For testing purposes I had "if" code to return true or false for the 
// commented out statements above. This meant those bits of code would 
// show all the checkboxes.
}
```

If you could help me to get the appropriate checkboxes shown and hidden, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this ll help but it's kind of what you want. I would think you would be able to use this as a base to what you are trying to do.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_events_hide

it comes from this page 
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass in a string, then use is as a Array.
If you pass in `ShowCheckBox("AgencyAgmt", 3)`,
In fact, you return the fouth character of "AgencyAgmt", you return 'n'
So your checking failed.

You should define like this:

```
var chkBoxValues = {};
chkBoxValues.MandatedMaterials = [true, true, false, false, false];
chkBoxValues.AgencyAgmt = [true, true, false, false, false];
return chkBoxValues[fieldName];
```

This will be work.

Comment: Thanks, @stevenfrog. You were a huge help. I had to spend a few hours wrestling with it to get my head wrapped around it, and here's the final result of the javascript code --         $scope.ShowCheckbox = function (fieldName, index) {
            var chkBoxValues = {};
            chkBoxValues.MandatedMaterials = [true, true],
            chkBoxValues.AgencyAgmt = [true, true]
            chkBoxValues.HOADocs = [,true]            
            return (chkBoxValues[fieldName])[index];
        }